# How to use sumifs for multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

i am looking to add a column values if it matches multiple criteria

i like to get sum of Column-c if Column-E range is in Column-B and Column-D = A1

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17RojhKkLbkkJ7o5dZjCrdeYAy48fK1O0yufbSg0GjlQ/edit?usp=sharing

i tried with single criteria using below formulae `=SUMPRODUCT(sumif(E4:E13,B4:B18,C4:C18))` but not able to add one more criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have multiple criteria you should go with `SUMIFS`

[image]

or do:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C4:C, D4:D="A1", COUNTIF(B4:B, E4:E)))
```

[image]